# React native / update array's object can call render?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I m studying about the cardviews, This cardview's UI is similar with FaceBook.

I store an array which have info about heart color at "state".

ex)

```
this.state = { 
heartarr : ["black","black","black" ...., "pink"...]
}
```

Then I make my Cardview with for loop.

This is the part of Cardview, the heart Icon.

```
<Icon
  color={this.state.heartarr[i]}
  size={30}
  name="heart">
</Icon>
```

At this situation, If I change the components in the "this.state.heartarr" with setState, the cardView never show me the color changes.

I change the heartArr like this function

```
var temp = this.state.heartarr;
if (this.state.heartarr[key] === "black") {
   temp[key] = "#e50914";
}
else {
   temp[key] = "black";
}
this.setState({ heartarr: temp })
```

The code is wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell, from where you are getting the key value.   Can you share some more bits of your code?

Comment: I set key in the touchableopacity with function, I pass the for loop's index at parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
this.setState({
    heartarr: [...[], ...temp]
})
```

Comment: this way is the different one with 
"this.setState({ heartarr: temp })" ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Here key is index of heartarr element.

```js
var clonedArray = this.state.heartarr.slice();

clonedArray[key] = clonedArray[key] === "black" ? "#e50914" : "black";

this.setState({ heartarr: clonedArray })
```